# jquery checkbox select all

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

I've got jquery all set up to find my select All check box, but for some reason it only selects all on the second click.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $("h2 #selectAllState").click(function () {

  var here = $(this).closest("div").attr('id');
  var stateDiv = "#"+here;
  var cityList = "#state"+here;


$(stateDiv+" h2 input:checkbox").change(function () {
        $(cityList).find(':checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });

});
```

Or is a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hXN2/73/)

Comment: You're not initializing the change function until the first click. What would you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original issue was that you weren't binding the `change` handler until the first click happened. I've fixed that and managed to simplify your code using traversal functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/w8ZLV/

```
$("#selectAllState").click(function () {    
    $(this).closest('div').find('.cityPick :checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Additionally, it looks like you might be repeating this block for other states, in which case you could have more than one element with the id `#selectAllState`, which isn't allowed. If my assumption is correct, that should be changed to a class instead of an id.

Comment: Awesome thanks!! Ya I'm using php to pull from a DB. I still haven't quite got my head around "this" so I over label things.